# Skype for Business & Lync 2010 Compatibility

Tags: microsoft-office, skype, lync, skype-for-business

I am looking at upgrading to Skype for Business (which is part of Office 2016) with my MSDN license at work. Currently we are using the 2010 version of Lync Server. Will Skype for Business connect to Lync? I've seen posts that people said they've seen Microsoft documentation that proclaims backwards compatibility, but I could not find those posts myself, so I'm hoping SU can help.

*Edit*

To clarify I want to know if the Skype for Business client is backwards compatible with the Lync 2010 server.

Comment: Backwards compatibility would indicate you could use a previous version of `Communicator` with the `Lync Server 2016` ( or whatever it is called ). `Lync Server 2010` supporting `Skype for Business` would be forward compatibility.  In either case the server would have to be configured to accept the client, so have you asked, your IT Administrator to do that?

Comment: @Ramhound Client backward compatibility is what I'm concerned about. I don't typically expect forward compatibility on the server side.

Comment: Right but you want to use `Skype for Business` with the `Lync Server 2010`.

Comment: Correct and for compatibility purposes I'd think the code would reside in the client, not the server. The client would be coded (if it was compatible) to work with the Lync 2010 protocol set, I wouldn't expect Lync 2010 to have been coded to work with protocols ahead of its time. I suppose I could have defined my question better -- you should be reading it as "Is Skype for Business backwards compatible with Lync 2010." I will update my question.

Comment: So my obvious follow-up question is, have you simply tried it, always good to determine if its a server or client compatibility problem (if one even exists).